# Как посчитать заполненность цели в процентах в PHP?

Tags: php

```
$goal = 100;
$currentCount = 50;
```

Мне нужно получить процент достижения цели в 100 юзеров. Текущее количество 50. Как посчитать процент между этими двумя числами? Нужно получить 50.

Comment: Чтобы вычислить процентное отношение чисел, нужно одно число разделить на другое и умножить на 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычная математика

```
$res = ($currentCount / $goal) * 100
```

Вывод: 50 ваших процентов. Понятно же, что 50 от 100 это 50%.